# Not able to apply slice to viewmodel knockout

Tags: model-view-controller, knockout.js

I am unable to apply slice or substr to `GId` due to the following error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "foreach: function (){return waititem }"
Message: Unable to process binding "style: function (){return { color:GId.slice(0,1) =='TR'?'black':'red'} }"
Message: undefined is not a function
```

**Html**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: waititem">
        <tr data-bind="style: { color: GId.slice(0,1) == 'TR'? 'black' : 'red' }">
            <td data-bind="text: PId"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: PName"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

How can I apply slice to check for the presence of a particular substring and style the row respectively?

Comment: Show your view-model

Comment: viewmodel.waititem is observablearray and contains collection of this model public class Visit
{
public string PName { get; set; } 
public string PId { get; set; } 
public string GId {get;set;}

}

Comment: What if you replace the style:{..} with style: {$parent.getColor} and getColor is a function that is similar to this: self.getColor = function(data){return data.GId.slice(0,1) == 'TR'? 'black' : 'red';}

Comment: From the syntax in your comment it appears you are using [tag:asp.net-mvc] and should tag the question accordingly if that is the case.

Comment: Having actual data would help, such as the output of `<span data-bind='text: ko.toJSON(waititem)'></span>` when placed above the `<table>`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the slice method in your `style` binding wrongly. You need to use the syntax of slice as

```
slice(start, end)
```

where start has default of 0 for initial position and end will be the end character. In your scenario the slice will return a string of *length 1* as you have used `slice(0,1)` but you are comparing with `'TR'` which is of *length 2*. Instead of that you need to use `slice(0, 2) === 'TR'`.

```
 <tr data-bind="style: { color: GId.slice(0,2) == 'TR'? 'black' : 'red' }">
      <td data-bind="text: PId"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: PName"></td>
 </tr>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dx3xdefu/)**

Comment: That's a problem, but it's not the cause of the error the OP is getting.